# CYK does not give the expected answer

Tags: algorithm, parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, cyk

I have implemented the CYK algorithm to check an input string with the given grammar.
And if I have the following grammar

```
S->AB|BC
A->BA|a
B->CC|b
C->AB|a
```

and if I check the string `ab` , the algorithm says it's in grammar. But if I have a grammar such as below,

```
S->ABC
A->a
B->i
C->h
```

and if I pass the string `aih`, the algorithm says it's not in the grammar. But as you can see, clearly `aih` will create the non-terminals `ABC` and they equal `S`. So I'm confused about this. Please point me if I'm wrong.. Thanks in advance.

```
   1    2     3

 1 A    null  null

 2 B    null

 3 C
```

EDIT: above shows how the algorithm constructs the words. in (1,3) its null. so its not in the grammar. Is it a problem with my grammar?

Comment: So what's your implementation?

Comment: I did the basic cyk implementation..which is the bottom up parsing.1st stage it matches each single input character with the grammar and after that it checks 2 inputs and so on...

Comment: I meant: We can't tell why it doesn't work if you don't show what you did.

Comment: I can post the code,,, but what i want to know is, whether is it correct conceptually? if i construct the outputs manually the algorithm should not say its correct, but as you can see its clearly matches the three outputs to the start symbol..so that's the problem I'm having.

Comment: Usually, for the CYK algorithm to work, the grammar has to be in Chomsky normal form. Your second grammar is not in this form, because it contains the rule `S->ABC`. This should be `S->S'C, S'->AB`

Comment: Thank you very much,,, So is it always has to be two non-terminals or less in the right side??

Comment: Thank again ..i totally missed that point and i found out how to build the correct CNF format as u mentioned.. :) its working perfectly now